# Mysql c# Mysql.Data.Mysqlclient.MysqlException (0x80004005): Unknown column 'lotete' in 'field list'

Tags: c#

Ok so i have error 'Mysql.Data.Mysqlclient.MysqlException (0x80004005): Unknown column 'lotete' in 'field list' when im trying to insert a new value

C# code

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`username`,`email`,`password`, `key`) VALUES (`lotete`, `test`, `xd`, `test2`)";
    if (connection != null)
    {
        connection.Open();
        MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = sql;
        try
        {
            //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", userName);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.LogError("MySQL error: " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Mysql:
http://prntscr.com/n0873w

Comment: Use regular quotes instead of backticks in your VALUES list. Backticks indicate a schema object name.

Comment: @Hammerite i can't because after when im using regular quotes i have error like 'You have an error in your SQL sytax;'

Comment: Show us the code that uses “regular quotes” and the error message you get. And that's [not how to store passwords](https://security.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/why-passwords-should-be-hashed/).

Comment: string sql = "INSERT INTO 'users' ('username','email','password', 'key') VALUES ('lotete', 'test', 'xd', 'test2')";

Comment: http://prntscr.com/n08ah9 @DourHighArch

Comment: Try this: string sql = "INSERT INTO \`users\` ('username','email','password', 'key') VALUES ('lotete', 'test', 'xd', 'test2')";

Comment: Post your schema and error messages [as text](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55251224/edit), not screenshots. Hammerite said to use regular quotes **in your VALUES list**, not everywhere. Backticks are for schema names, like your table and column names. String values have to be in apostrophes. Please go through a MySQL tutorial.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a *typographic error* because it's caused by your using the wrong quote types in the `VALUES` clause. You should be using single quotes around the column values, not backticks. Doing so does not produce another error; if it does, then you've not posted your actual code.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Parameters for command to prevent SQL Injection.

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO users(username,email,password, key) VALUES(@username, @email, @password, @key)";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", "lotete");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", "test@test.com");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", "testtest");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@key", "test2");
```

Comment: Still syntax error, should i add (id) VALUES (NULL) to Parameters?
http://prntscr.com/n08dkj

Comment: If you're getting an error you need to tell us the error. You probably need backticks around all schema names.